# use method reset of unique_prt:free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

When I use reset to rebind the `unique_ptr`, something bad happens but when use `std::make_unique`, everything is ok.

```cpp
int main() {
    unique_ptr<string> p= nullptr;
    auto l=[&p]()->void{
        static string x {"1111"};
        cout<<x<<endl;
        //p = std::make_unique<string>(x);// compile ok
        p.reset(&x);//compile error free():invalid pointer; 
        cout<<p.get()<<endl;
        return;
    };
    l();
    cout<<p->length()<<endl;
    cout<<p.get()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I think that when the reset method is called, the string object is not really handed over to the `unique_ptr` management. When leaving the scope, the dtor is called twice

Comment: please do note remove includes and using declarations from your code before posting it here. They are part of the code. Everybody who wants to compile and run your code will have to add them back. Read about [mcve]. And please do not psot images of text. Include error messages as text in the question. Its not a compile error btw

Comment: whats the aim of the code? Why do you call `reset` ? Why would you want a `static` string to be managed by a unique pointer?

Comment: Ehr... what!?!? You want to transfer "ownership" of a static variable to a unique pointer? That's just not possible. could do static std::unique_ptr<std::string> x = std::make_unique<std::string>("1111");` however for std::string that also makes no sense (it is already dynamically allocated) So WHAT do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both variants do compile without errors (provided one adds the missing parts). Your code invokes undefined behavior and likely crashes at runtime.

When you use `std::make_unique` like this:

```
p = std::make_unique<string>(x);
```

Then `std::make_unique` constructs a `std::unique_ptr` that manages the lifetime of a `std::string` that is constructed as a copy of `x`. You now have two strings, `x` and the one managed by `p`.

When you use `reset` like this:

```
p.reset(&x);
```

You tell `p` to take ownership of `x`. However, `x` is not dynamically allocated. It makes no sense to transfer its ownership to a smart pointer. When `p`s destructor is called it will attempt to `delete &x` but `x` was not allocated via `new`, hence there is undefined behavior. When the program terminates the lifetime of the static string ends and `x` is destroyed (again).

---

> I think that when the reset method is called, the string object is not really handed over to the unique_ptr management.

Yes it is. And that is the problem.

---

It is not clear what the actual purpose of the code is. To return string from the lambda:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto l=[](){
        std::string x {"1111"};
        std::cout << x << std::endl;        
        return x;
    };
    auto p = l();
    std::cout << p.length() << std::endl;
}
```